# Getting error as string indices must be integers while using for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

i have a list of dict as:

out:

```
[
    {
        "dest_host": "AA",
        "sysname": "",
        "mgmt_ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "platform": "switch",
        "remote_port": "E1/48",
        "local_port": "G0/2",
        "version": "",
        "interface_ip": ""
    },
    {
        "dest_host": "BB",
        "sysname": "",
        "mgmt_ip": "1.1.1.2",
        "platform": "switch",
        "remote_port": "E1/40",
        "local_port": "G0/1",
        "version": "",
        "interface_ip": ""
    }]
```

this is my for loop:

```
for i in out:
                  print('port:'+i['local_port'],'--->','nei_host:'+i['dest_host'],'--->','nei_port:'+i['remote_port'])
```

error -

```
    print('port:'+i['local_port'],'--->','nei_host:'+i['dest_host'],'--->','nei_port:'+i['remote_port'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

what i would like to print:

```
port:G0/2 --> nei_host:AA ---> nei_port:E1/48
port:G0/1 --> nei_host:BB ---> nei_port:E1/40
```

Can some one help me to find the error in for loop. I am new to python. Thanks

Comment: Is this all of your code? It works perfectly for me

Comment: Offhand I'd say `out` is not what you claim it is.  Use `print(repr(out))` to be sure.

Comment: Is `out` explicitly a dictionary, or is it a JSON string?

Comment: @csjh i have `out = json.dumps(cdpnei, indent = 4)` , when i print (out) i do see list of dict, so i am assuming out is a dictonary.

Comment: No. `out` is a string.  The string LOOKS like a dictionary, because that's what JSON does, but the dictionary is `cdpnei`.

Comment: @MarkRansom `'[\n    {\n        "dest_host": " AA",\n        "sysname": "",\n        "mgmt_ip": "1.1.1.1",\n        "platform": "switch",\n        "remote_port": "E1/48",\n        "local_port": "G0/2",\n        "version": "",\n        "interface_ip": ""\n    },\n    {\n        "dest_host": "BB",\n        "sysname": "",\n        "mgmt_ip": "1.1.1.2",\n        "platform": "switch",\n        "remote_port": "E1/40",\n        "local_port": "G0/1",\n        "version": "",\n        "interface_ip": ""\n    }\n]'`

Comment: @TimRoberts `for i in cdpnei:` did worked.

port:G0/2 --> nei_host:AA ---> nei_port:E1/48
port:G0/1 --> nei_host:BB ---> nei_port:E1/40

Comment: So what you have is a single string that *looks* like a list of dictionaries.  The for loop is delivering every character of that string one at a time.

Comment: @j1-lee JSON is designed for Javascript syntax, not Python.  The two are similar but not identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
cdpnei = ssh.send_command('show cdp neigh detail', use_textfsm=True)
out = json.dumps(cdpnei, indent = 4)
```

i was assuming out is dict, so i was running for loop against `out`

as @TimRoberts suggested , i ran for loop against `cdpnei` which is actual dictionary

```
for i in cdpnei:
                  print('port:'+i['local_port'],'--->','nei_host:'+i['dest_host'],'--->','nei_port:'+i['remote_port'])
```

that did a trick, worked as expected.

```
port:G0/2 --> nei_host:AA ---> nei_port:E1/48
port:G0/1 --> nei_host:BB ---> nei_port:E1/40
```